# Why is objFolder.CopyHere copying the "wrong way?"

Tags: vba, excel

I recently posted trying to figure out how to copy/paste some files via VBA using the Windows copy file notification.  I have found out that my script works, but it is copying the files from the location I want to copy them to, and pasting them in the location I want to copy from (exactly opposite).  Can anyone explain to me why?  Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Main()

'***************************************************************************
' Personal details
'***************************************************************************

    'Ask if the user wants to continue
    If MsgBox("Do you wish to continue (Outlook will close)?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then
        ThisWorkbook.Close
        End
    End If

        'Close Outlook so it doesn't interfere with the file copy
        strComputer = "."
        Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
        Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'Outlook.exe'")
        For Each objProcess In colProcessList
            Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            objOutlook.Quit
        Next

        If Len(Dir("\\[NetDrive]\[EmpNum]$\")) <> 0 Then
            If Len(Dir("C:\Users\[EmpNum]\Documents\Outlook Files\")) <> 0 Then

                    'Taken from multiple examples
                    'http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/238407-progress-bar-copying-file.html

                    Dim FromPath As Variant
                    Dim ToPath As Variant

                    FromPath = "C:\Users\[EmpNum]\Documents\Outlook Files\"  '<< Change for implicit reference
                    ToPath = "\\[NetDrive]\[EmpNum]$\Personal Folder Backup"    '<< Change for implicit reference

                    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))       'Delay to allow Outlook to close

                    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
                    '//The source Folder to CopyFrom:
                    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(FromPath)

                    '//The source Folder to CopyTo:
                    objFolder.CopyHere ToPath, &H10&

                    Set objShell = Nothing
                    Set objFolder = Nothing

                    MsgBox "You can find the files and subfolders from " & FromPath & " in " & ToPath
            Else
                MsgBox "Personal folder location not found.  Please check your personal folder."
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Network location not available.  Check your shared drives for connection."
        End If

        Application.Quit

End Sub
```

I have removed and/or changed a couple personal details, but other than that this is my code exactly.

Comment: Very good information regarding file or folder management with VBA: [RonDeBruin](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win026.htm)

Comment: That is what I started with, @DawidSATokyo, but I changed to the objShell.CopyHere because the other method does not display the Windows copy file status window.

Comment: Aren't u missing the \ at the end of 'Personal Folder Backup'?

Comment: @DawidSATokyo yes I was, but the behavior didn't change when I put it back in.

Comment: If it's doing exactly the opposite, just switch the path?

Comment: Is the clue not in the `CopyHere` name? ;) It's not `CopyTo` or `CopyThere` after all...

Comment: @findwindow I tried that and it error'd out.

Comment: @Rory, you may be on to something.  One moment.

Comment: @Rory, I get an error "Object doesn't support this property or method" if I change it to `CopyTo` ... I guess you were just being facetious, because I do want to copy it to `ToPath` location.

Comment: Huh. How can it go one way but not the exact opposite?! I didn't read code though just figured vice versa has to work XD

Comment: @findwindow yeah, Idk.  I ended up modifying my code based on the code [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-21472173960), and now it works?  I will post the working code below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this worked this time and it didn't before.  But I modified my code to read what I have below, and now it suddenly works correctly:

```
Private Sub Main()

'***************************************************************************
'  Personal Information
'***************************************************************************

    'Ask if the user wants to continue
    If MsgBox("Do you wish to continue (Outlook will close)?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then
        ThisWorkbook.Close
        End
    End If

        'Close Outlook so it doesn't interfere with the file copy
        strComputer = "."
        Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
        Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'Outlook.exe'")
        For Each objProcess In colProcessList
            Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            objOutlook.Quit
        Next

        If Len(Dir("\\[NetDrive]\[EmpNum]$\")) <> 0 Then
            If Len(Dir("C:\Users\[EmpNum]\Documents\Outlook Files\")) <> 0 Then

                    'Taken from multiple examples
                    'http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/238407-progress-bar-copying-file.html

                    Dim FromPath As Variant
                    Dim ToPath As Variant

                    FromPath = "C:\Users\[EmpNum]\Documents\Outlook Files\"  '<< Change for implicit reference
                    ToPath = "\\[NetDrive]\[EmpNum]$\Personal Folder Backup\"    '<< Change for implicit reference

                    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))       'Delay to allow Outlook to close

                    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
'                    '//The source Folder to CopyFrom:
'                    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(FromPath)
'
'                    '//The source Folder to CopyTo:
'                    objFolder.CopyHere ToPath, &H10&
'
'                    Set objShell = Nothing
'                    Set objFolder = Nothing

                       Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(ToPath)

                       If (Not objFolder Is Nothing) Then
                           objFolder.CopyHere (FromPath)
                       End If

                       Set objFolder = Nothing
                       Set objShell = Nothing

                    MsgBox "You can find the files and subfolders from " & FromPath & " in " & ToPath
            Else
                MsgBox "Personal folder location not found.  Please check your personal folder."
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Network location not available.  Check your shared drives for connection."
        End If

        Application.Quit

End Sub
```

I guess the only difference is the `&H10&` isn't there anymore.

Comment: No - you changed `objFolder` to use `ToPath` not `FromPath`. That's what made the difference.

Comment: @Rory, well, I didn't even see that.  Although it's really weird, because I tried switching `FromPath` and `ToPath` in the previous code, and it gave me an error.